# Symfony Project Works in Dev, Throws 404 or 500 in Prod, What to Check?

Tags: symfony

I attempted to switch my Symfony project from `APP_ENV=dev` to `APP_ENV=prod` for the first time.

When I visit the root path home page and most other routes, I get:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

The only variation I can find is on one specific route, where I get:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
> error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
> inconvenience caused.

When in prod, nothing is logged to the site's var/log directory and nothing is logged to /var/log/php

I tried clearing the cache.  I also checked `bin/console debug:router --env=prod` and the results were normal.

When I switch back to the dev environment, the problem goes away.

The project is running with Symfony 5.4 on Ubuntu on my own development server.

What else can I check to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very close but found the wrong info about caching.

This DOES NOT fix the problem:  `bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer`

That came from https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache

Here is the solution:

`bin/console cache:clear`

Found at https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/prod-environment#clearing-the-prod-cache